# How to add navigationController to existing tab application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone application with 2 tabs. This is my application delegate:

```
 (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
 }
```

My first tab is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. I would like to push a new view controller when someone clicks on a row of my table. I know that this is done in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
TableViewDetailViewController *fvController = [[TableViewDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvController animated:YES];
    [fvController release];
    fvController = nil;
```

My `self.navigationController` is NIL so nothing gets pushed to the view stack. Where should I create my navigationController, so there would be as little code to change as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have direct solution using **Interface builder**.

In **interface builder** go to `xib` in which you have added `tabBarController` and delete the `tabBarItem` with which you have connected your `tableViewController` .

Now, drag and drop an `UINavigationController` from library in your `tabBar` and set this `navigationController`'s `rootViewController` as your `tableViewController`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your `TableViewDetailViewController` as one of your tabbbars ViewControllers, you should create an `UINavigationController` for each tab on your tabbar. Then place your TableViewDetailViewController inside the corresponding `UINavigationController`. `self.navigationController` will point to a valid `UINavigationController` in that case.